# Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 - Startup issue in UNIX

Tags: activemq-classic

I am facing problem when I am starting the ActiveMQ server in UNIX machine.

I just simply install a fresh copy by download and extract. I have not changed any configuration .

Downloaded file :- `apache-activemq-5.9.0.bin.tar.gz`

Then I extracted and try to start.

```
/apache-activemq-5.9.0/bin/linux-x86-64 


[aaa@addr:17.169.98.231 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> ./activemq start
Starting ActiveMQ Broker...
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> 
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> 
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xx> ./activemq status
ActiveMQ Broker is running (5439).
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> ./activemq status
ActiveMQ Broker is running (5439).
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> ./activemq status
ActiveMQ Broker is not running.
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> ./activemq status
ActiveMQ Broker is not running.
```

Now the server is not running.
After few second it is stopping.Why ?

**Start on Console:-**

```
[aaa@addr:17.34.34.34 linux-x86-64]$:/ngs/app/xxx> ./activemq console

Running ActiveMQ Broker...
wrapper  | WARNING: Could not write lock file /var/lock/subsys/ActiveMQ: Permission denied
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 1    | wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 2    | wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 3    | wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 4    | wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 5    | wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
wrapper  | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
wrapper  |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Any mistake I am doing.
I have googled many links and articles but fail to find the solution.
RabbitMQ is already running on this machine.

Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It got solved.

ActiveMQ requires JDK not JRE , which was not installed in my machine.

I have installed the JDK, now its working.